# Kibana can't retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elastic-stack

i am trying to install `kibana` and  `elasticsearch` through a `docker-compose.yml` file and I got

`{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-01-09T18:24:14+00:00","tags":["error","elasticsearch-service"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN elasticsearch"}`,
from logs of the `kibana` container. the `elasticsearch` container work fine. Can you help me please figure out what is the problem?

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: logex/web
    build:
      context: front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: logex-front
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    networks:
      - web-network
    depends_on:
      - server

  server:
    image: logex/server
    build:
      context: logex_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        DATA_PATH: ${LOGEX_RECOVERY_BASE_DIR}
    container_name: logex-app
    command: "api"
    volumes:
      - logex-data:${LOGEX_RECOVERY_BASE_DIR}
    networks:
      - server-network
    ports:
      - "${LOGEX_API_PORT}:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbit
      - elastic

  mongo:
    container_name: logex-mongo
    image: "bitnami/mongodb:6.0"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MONGODB_DATABASE=${LOGEX_DB_NAME}
      - MONGODB_ROOT_USER=${LOGEX_DB_USERNAME}
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${LOGEX_DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${LOGEX_DB_PORT}:27017"
    networks:
      - server-network
    volumes:
      - "mongo-data:/bitnami/mongodb"

  elastic:
    container_name: logex-elastic
    image: "bitnami/elasticsearch:7.17.10"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_NUMBER=${LOGEX_SE_PORT}
    ports:
      - "${LOGEX_SE_PORT}:${LOGEX_SE_PORT}"
    networks:
      - server-network
    volumes:
      - "elastic-data:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data"
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  rabbit:
    container_name: logex-rabbit
    image: "bitnami/rabbitmq:3.10.5-debian-11-r11"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_USERNAME=${LOGEX_MQ_USERNAME}
      - RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=${LOGEX_MQ_PASSWORD}
      - RABBITMQ_VHOST=${LOGEX_MQ_VIRTUAL_HOST}
    ports:
      - "${LOGEX_MQ_PORT}:5672"
    networks:
      - server-network
    volumes:
      - "rabbit-data:/bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia"

  kibana:
    container_name: logex-kibana
    image: "bitnami/kibana:7.17.10"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://logex-elastic:${LOGEX_SE_PORT}
    ports:
      - "${LOGEX_KIBANA_PORT}:${LOGEX_KIBANA_PORT}"
    networks:
      - server-network
    depends_on:
      - elastic

volumes:
  mongo-data:
  elastic-data:
    driver: local
  kibana-data:
    driver: local
  rabbit-data:
  logex-data:

networks:
  server-network:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc: "true"

  web-network:
    driver: bridge
```

i have already inspect logs for both kibana and elasticsearch  container. elastic search container's work fine but the kibana one doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Kibana has connection problems with elasticsearch. I had a similar issue three times (not containerized).

In the first one the culprit was the ELASTICSEARCH_HOST. I had a typo.

In the second one it was the firewall between my servers.

In the third one it was the built in kibana user culprit.

[Kibana built in roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-roles.html)